# Most efficient way for checking if mongo document already exist? Query for existing or set index to unique?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm looking through a somewhat popular authorization utility, and noticed this:

```
User.findOne({
        email: req.body.email.toLowerCase()
    }, function (err, existingUser) {
        if (existingUser) {
            return res.status(409).send({
                message: 'Email is already taken'
            });
        }
```

Would it be more efficient to just set the user email to a unique index and handle the error for that, rather than querying to check for one that already exist?

Comment: It will take same time. If you find doc by index or try to insert with already existed unique index mongo process time will be the same. But my opinion i that better to check, than rely on mongodb errors. Because if something changes inside driver and you will not be aware you'll get a mess.

Comment: Thanks. Do you want to submit this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to check, than rely on mongodb errors. 
Because if something changes inside driver and you will not be aware you'll get a mess.

For example. Mongo version 4.0 will not throw errors on unique index and just replace data with corresponding fields.

Or some developer change createNewUser method and instead of save it now uses update if we have error.

Or something similar.

With validation of email field you will prevent all of those issues and a lot of pain in future.

Hope this helps.